# Retrieving data from api - Android studio, Kotlin

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new at kotlin and Android studio in general. I want to create an application in which the user will enter certain data and according to this data, the result from api will be retrieved, which best corresponds to the entered data. Can anyone give me advice on where to start or suggest some tutorial?So far I have done the design and created certain xml files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can checkout [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) it is an android library used for networking / api calls. There are multiple tutorials available for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use retrofit, I suggest you [this article](https://rahul9650ray.medium.com/how-to-implement-rest-api-in-android-using-retrofit-in-kotlin-part-1-1302cb0d978b)